# `exec` kills script

Tags: ruby, exec

Running `sdiff` through `exec` causes my script to exit without errors. Even the ensure block does not get run:

```
begin
  puts "I occur"
  exec("sdiff onefile.csv anotherfile.csv > filediffs.txt")
rescue Exception => e
  puts "I do not get printed"
  puts e
ensure
  puts "I do not get printed"
end
puts "I used to get printed, repeatedly, now not, repeatedly"
```

It was working as expected for a while, then it started mysteriously exiting and the conditions are the same. No terminal output after "I occur".

Comment: ah, I must have been mistaken about it continuing to run the code following it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the expected behaviour of the `exec` method, the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) about it says:

> Replaces the current process by running the given external command

You probably want to use [`system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) instead of `exec`.

Answer (score 1):

`exec` will replace the current process by the command passed as argument to it. After `exec()` has been executed the calling process won't exist anymore.

Check [this](http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/03/08/5_ways_to_run_commands_from_ruby/) for reference and alternatives.